# Node.js: Not able to connect UPOS fiscal printer using TCP/IP

Tags: node.js, tcp, tcpclient, fiscal-printer

I've connected Exorigo UPOS fiscal printer(*model: FPT88FVA*) to router using Ethernet cable and want to connect the printer over wifi using TCP/IP protocol from my device, so I've written the below code in **Node.js**.  I've used `net module` to create `tcp client` and tried to make connection with printer, but it's not working (doesn't print `connected` message on console). `Not getting any error or response`.
may be I'm missing something, I tried other ways too but no luck.

Can someone please provide a suggestion what to look for?

```
var net = require('net');

// ESC MFB O ESC MFE
// 0x1B 0x80 0x4F 0x1B 0x83

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(6090, '192.168.029.203', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('0x1B 0x80 0x4F 0x1B 0x83');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Comment: Is there any update on this question? Were you able to fix it?